# modified date or create date modification on Task import using DataLoader

Tags: data-loader, standard-objects, activities, import

I am having an issue importing Task using Dataloader.  When I import it creates a new CreateDate per task imported.  Can the CreateDate be modified to its original create date?

Comment: You can import Createdate into a custom field and then write a Apex code to re-populate custom fields to Createdate field. But it will update your modified date.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are doing Data Migration. You can definitely set any SObject createDate to a user-defined value by using the following feature in Setup [(taken from Help doc)](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Enabling-Create-Audit-Fields&language=en_US):

```
Setup -> Customize -> User Interface -> Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation"
```

and

```
Setup  -> Customize -> User Interface -> Enable "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions
```

This used to require a support ticket but no more.